# Google Drive Downloading Problems

Tags: google-drive-api

Can I download the files stored in My Google Drive without signing into the gmail Account.
Since I have access to google drive but not to gmail account.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the security settings you apply, if you are setting resources or document with settings like "anyone with the link can access" ,then probably it's open to all whom your provide the link,the user may be Google User or Non-Google User

> After October 2013, document sharing to specific email addresses works
>   a bit differently. Recipients with a Google Account will still login
>   to access a shared file. That remains the same.
>
> Recipients without a Google Account may now view the document, with no
>   Google Account required. This will make basic document sharing with
>   non-Google Account users much simpler.
>
> Document collaboration still requires a Google Account: a user must
>   login to comment on or make edits to a document. But no Google Account
>   will be required for a user to view a document shared to them at a
>   non-Google Account email address.